# While writing webdriverio test, 'browser' keyword is not getting identified

Tags: webdriver-io

I am using webdriverio v7.5.7. While writing test, browser keyword not getting identified. It is auto correcting to Bhxbrowser. Any idea ?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to stackoverflow! I am afraid this is not the best way to ask questions if you are really looking for solutions. It would be good to have a link to your code hosted in github/gitlab or sample config with error logs. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face the same problem but found the solution on their official site.

You need to create **jsconfig.json** file and save it in your project folder.

**Mocha**:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": [
            "node",
            "webdriverio/sync",
            "@wdio/mocha-framework"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Cucumber**:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": [
            "node",
            "webdriverio/async",
            "@wdio/cucumber-framework"
        ]
    }
}
```

Reference to the solution:
https://webdriver.io/docs/autocompletion/#visual-studio-code-vscode

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29004064)

Comment: @camille I addressed that, looks much better